# Can Google Maps API calculate route along multiple locations or journey legs?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps API Web Services [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) or the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/) to find the travel distance and time between locations.

It seems that the API only supports calculation of the route between one origin and one destination. (In case of the Distance Matrix API, multiple combinations directly between origins and destinations are computed.)

My case is that I would like to know the route (really, just traveling time and distance) of a multiple-leg journey along a series (as in an ordered array) of locations.

So, considering four locations, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, I know how to compute the route between any pair, `A-B`, `A-C`, `A-D`, `B-C` and so on. I want to compute the route of `A-B-C-D` or `A-C-D-B` or `A-D-B-C`and so on. I supply the route and the order of the legs, so I'm not asking to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem.

Is this possible with the Google Maps Directions API or Distance Matrix API?

Obviously, I can chain the locations myself, so ask for the routes of the individual legs in separate calls, and then add them together in the desired order: `A-C` + `C-D` + `D-B` becomes `A-C-D-B`. I'm hoping that it's possible with one call.

(I've looked for similar questions, but haven't found this exact one.)

Comment: For people downvoting this question, please be so helpful to explain _why_ you're downvoting it. Wrong question? Duplicate? (If so, with which one?) Not relevant? Just downvoting isn't helpful.

Comment: You need to add the intermediate points as [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) in the Directions API (can't be done with the DistanceMatrix API)

Comment: @geocodezip, if you write that down as an answer, I'll be happy to accept that. It indeed is a solution.

Comment: What if you don't know the B and C beforehand? That is, you want the travel distance and time between A and D, but you don't care if you take two trains and a bus or a bus and walking? Google Maps online does that - can one do it with Directions or Distance APIs? (I think not)

Comment: @yotiao, check the optional parameters on the Google Maps Directions API, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro. You can request `alternatives` and multiple `transit_mode`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @geocodezip, the answer is to add 'waypoints' between the origin and the destination, as described in the [documentation of the Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints).

For example, the request `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA` calculates the route between Boston and Concord via Charlestown and Lexington.

And the Traveling Salesman Problem is partly being solved as well, per

> By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass `optimize:true` as the first argument within the waypoints parameter to allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order.